# Proper Use of Static Libraries in Eclipse CDT

Tags: c++, eclipse, static-libraries

I've built a static library of general utilities I use in a lot of my C++ projects. However, I realize now that I don't know how to index those libraries into an eclipse project. I don't mean link the libraries into the project at compile-time--I mean index them so that every time I use something from those libraries it doesn't tell me there's an error.

However, being that static libraries are all in object code, I'm thinking this just might not be possible. In that case, how *do* you properly use static libraries in Eclipse? I'm fortunate that i have the source code for mine, but what if I wanted to use a library for which I didn't have the source code? Would everything have to be done with forward declaration?

This may be more a general coding question than an Eclipse-specific problem, per se.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't have the code then you cannot index it with Eclipse AFAIK. I use lots of 3rd party code in Eclipse but all of them have the source code also.

Forward declaration would do you no good in terms of indexing either, it is just a method of telling the compiler what something is without having the full definitions. This would let the indexer know that something was a class, but that is all. It would not give you access to members list for auto-complete or anything like that.

Comment: Fair enough, but then in that case, what is the point of creating a static library if you ultimately need the code (if you're in an IDE environment)? I really created the library just to create a library -- but if I have to include the source code anyway, there's not much point of using it, is there?

Comment: If you have the source code, you can just tell the compiler where the headers are and it will index it. Even with a static library you will need to use the header files in order for it to compile anyway.

Comment: I know that forward declaring wouldn't do any good with indexing, but I think it would at least prevent Eclipse from thinking there's an error.

Comment: Ah. I did not know that about the headers with a library. I'm new to using libraries. /grin. Thanks!

Comment: Tom I think that you have misunderstood the use of static libs. Both static and dynamic libs require that you have access to the definitions of the objects within them that you want to use. The only difference is that the static libs are linked into your own code instead at link time rather than used dynamically at runtime via a DLL. EDIT : Yep just saw your reply... yeah you need headers with libraries still.

Comment: I too think I misunderstood them. It was a fun project creating it anyway (I did learn quite a bit in doing so...even though "the point" may not have been one of those things).